# Sort order for two tables using group by

Tags: mysql, sorting, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have two tables, event and version. An event has many versions. I want to perform an inner join and get THE LAST version for each event. (Original question was here: [Join two tables and apply group by, but change sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49538793/join-two-tables-and-apply-group-by-but-change-sort-order))

I've changed the tables to this. I think it makes more sense. But I am in the same situation, I don't understand how to get the max version id per event. I'd like to understand the logic behind the solution. Feel free to give me feedback on table structure. Thanks!

Query:

```
SELECT e.id AS event_id,v.* 
FROM events.event e
INNER JOIN events.version v
ON (v.event_id = e.id)
GROUP BY v.event_id
```

EVENT

```
Id   Updated
1    03/08/18
2    06/06/18
```

VERSION

```
Id Event_id      Name            Description        
7  1             Dinner          Dinner Z           
8  2             Breakfast       Breakfast Y   
9  2             Breakfast       Breakfast X
```

Comment: select max(v.id),v.*,e.* from EVENT as e inner join VERSION as v on e.Id=v.Event_id group by v. Event_id

try the query, I think it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the last version in an event is characterized by having the largest `ID` value, we can try the following query:

```
SELECT
    e.id AS event_id,
    v1.*
FROM event e
INNER JOIN version v1
    ON e.id = v1.event_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT event_id, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM version
    GROUP BY event_id
) v2
    ON v1.event_id = v2.event_id AND
       v1.id = v2.max_id;
```

You will notice that the first join in the above query is what you were already doing.  I simply added a join to a new subquery which finds the most recent event for each version.

Comment: Worked perfect! (Only a syntax error on "ON e.id. = v1.event_id". The dot after id )

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(v.id),v.*,e.* from EVENT as e inner join VERSION as v on e.Id=v.Event_id group by v. Event_id
```

try the query, I think it works fine.

Comment: With this query, there is no guarantee that the values returned for `v.*` are going to be from the *same* row where the maximum `v.id` value is found. This query pattern executes in MySQL because of a MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY, when `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is omitted from sql_mode.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  (without noting the caveats, this query example is bad advice to someone that is trying to learn/understand SQL)